# Fixed byte array default value comparison

Tags: solidity

What is the correct way to see if a bytesN value is of "default" value; whatever value is assigned to it upon declaration?

The following works, but seems unsafe:

```
contract Assertnil {
    bytes32 v;
    function test() constant returns (bool) {
        assert(v == "");
        return true;
    }
}
```

This seems more correct, but slightly more expensive:

```
contract Assertnil {
    bytes32 v;
    function test() constant returns (bool) {
        bytes32 w;
        assert(v == w);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no attribute or function asserting default value, only by comparison. [Assembly](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html?highlight=Assembly) is a good way and more cheaper, a simple demo as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract test{

    bytes32 v ;

    function isEmpty() returns (bool flag){
        assembly {
            flag := eq(eq(sload(v_slot),0),1)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: I tried that as is and it wouldn't compile, but when I move bytes32 v into the function and changed v_slot to v and tried solc --gas it came out more expensive than just testing v == ""

Comment: Please tell me error log, i test everything is ok. If you move into function, generating variable will consume 183 gas, so more expensive. `sload` will cost more less because of loading from stack, not new.

Comment: My bad, it's a version incompatibility. It breaks on the 0.4.16 nightly build: `abltest.sol:9:33: Error: Identifier not found or not unique
            flag := eq(eq(sload(v_slot),0),1)` but latest stable 0.4.15 is OK.

However, I only get a saving of 3 gas vs `== ""` (398 vs 401) and the latter is better when using `--optimize` (368 vs 362).